# Ignore parameters in url using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

So I have the following route /path1/path2/{value1}/path3/{value2} and I'm trying to figure out if the request route matches path1 path2 and path3  regardless the {value1} and {value2} which change.

This is what I have but its not matching:

```
    @Test
public void testURLMatches() {
    String input = "/path1/path2/123/path3/456";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\/path1\\/path2\\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})\\/path3\\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Does match!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Does not match!");
    }
    assertTrue(matcher.find());
}
```

Edit 1:
Added in the pattern \/ which was missing originally

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: [split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: I want to get the regex to work, so basically when a url comes in like /path1/path2/123/path3/456 to match the regex. how this regex looks like I do not know. I think should look like: \\/path1\\/path2([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})\\/path3\\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}) but is not working

Comment: I think your missing a forward slash after path2 . I tested in https://regex101.com/ Should be something like this: \/path1\/path2\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,})\/path3\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}).

Comment: @dawg cannot use a split.

Comment: @Kirsteen good catch tired adding the slash after path2 but still is not working. trying your sample

Comment: Are you sure you want to use find()? See javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()
 Maybe you want to use matches() to match the whole input string. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()

Comment: @Kirsteen tried matches too still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Regex you are looking at is

```
^\/path1\/path2\/([\w]+)\/path3\/([\w]+)$
```

PS : You have another problem in your test, you call the matcher.find() functions twice, whereas you should only call it once. Remove the if condition.

In Java, you get

```
@Test
public void testURLMatches() {
    String input = "/path1/path2/123/path3/456";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\/path1\\/path2\\/([\\w]+)\\/path3\\/([\\w]+)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    assertTrue(matcher.find());
}
```

([example](https://regex101.com/r/4Y2XQX/1))

Comment: In java changed it to "^\\/path1\\/path2\\/([\\w]+)\\/path3\\/([\\w]+)$" but still did not do the trick.

Comment: Just ran it worked. I guess had something to do with calling the matcher.find twice

Comment: @otc Perfect ! Do not hesitate to class the post as resolved if it helped you

Comment: Done. Not sure why for downvoting though, I feel this is could be a common problem for java jersey servlet routes.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match because you need a / after: /path2, try this and it will work:

```
string input = "/path1/path2/123/path3/456";
string pattern = @"\/path1\/path2\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}\/path3\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
    // match
}
else
{
    // not match
}
```

It is not very clear for me what is the accepted values for {Value}, but you can use this, as well:

```
\/path1\/path2\/[\w]*\/path3\/[\w]*
```

[\w]*: zero or more occurrence of any alphanumeric char

Comment: {value1} or {value2} can be replaced with anything during run time.

Comment: Yes, what I mean was, what type of char is allowed in value: your regex captures alphabets and numbers... so I was asking, what if the value contains something like: _ or . or ~ or - etc.